# Keep image view fixed to right of linear layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a header, which is a linear layout and has a text view and an image view.

```
< LinearLayout
<TextView 
  android:layout_weight="8"
  ...
  / >
 <ImageView
  android:layout_weight="2"
 ...
 /> 
< /LinearLayout >
```

In portrait mode, everything is perfect, but in landscape mode, because the size of the header increases, the imageview moves a bit to the left.

I want to be able to fix the image view to the right side of the header, regardless of the orientation.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You may want to think about using  RelativeLayout. If you do, you can just use android:alignParentRight="true"

Comment: if your root layout is relative, you could set textview `android:alignParentLeft` on true and also set `android:layout_toLeftOf` by putting imageview's id. And of course set params for imageview `android:alignParentRight` on true

Answer (score 0):

Just set ImageView's layout_width and layout_height to "wrap_content" and remove layout_weight. That way, TextView will fill all available space to the left of ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView 
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
     <ImageView 
         android:src="@drawables/my_image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
< LinearLayout
...>
<TextView 
  android:layout_weight="8"
  ...
  / >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:alignParentRight="true"
         ...
    />    
</RelativeLayout>

< /LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code, it will assign all the available space to the texView, shifting the imageView to right side of the layout:

```
< LinearLayout
<TextView 
android:layout_weight="1"
...
/ >
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/> 
< /LinearLayout >
```